# What are the rules surrounding a hyphen following an abbreviation?

Tags: abbreviations, hyphenation, periods, compound-adjectives

For instance, if something is owned by Apple Inc. does that make the compound phrasal adjective 'Apple Inc.-owned'? Or would I omit the period?

Comment: You can only omit the period if you expand the word to its full form (*Apple Incorporated*). But even with that, the hyphen would look wrong. Rephrase it. *Owned by Apple Inc.*

Comment: Why Inc? Apple-owned should be evident from the context.

Answer (score 1):

This is a question of style, and different style manuals may give different recommendations. I will be following the *Chicago Manual of Style* (CMOS).

**If you can, rephrase**

The best recommendation in any unusual case is to rephrase. In your case, you could do it along the lines suggested by either Jason Bassford or jimm101.

However, if you really can't or would prefer not to rephrase, read on.

**Don't remove the period**

First of all, CMOS says that abbreviations which end with a lowercase letter should contain a period after that letter (with some rare exceptions that don't apply here). Second, for *Apple Inc.,* the period is part of the proper name, and CMOS says that respecting the form of the proper name takes precedence over whatever other rules there may be (see e.g. [here](https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/HyphensEnDashesEmDashes/faq0066.html)). So on both counts, CMOS would frown upon removing the period after *Inc.*

**A hyphen may follow a period**

CMOS does allow for things like *U.S.-oriented*, as documented in this entry from their Q&A ([here](https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/HyphensEnDashesEmDashes/faq0072.html)):

> Q. I’m interested in how you would treat the following issue of double punctuation:
>
> U.S.-oriented.
>
> I decided to omit the hyphen, which I would have otherwise used, because I didn’t like the way it looked following an abbreviation period.
>
> A. It may look a little odd, but the hyphen is conventional there, because omitting it could cause readers to mistake “oriented” for a verb. If your publication’s style permits, you can follow *CMOS 16* in omitting the periods: US-oriented.

**Replace the hyphen by an en dash**

There is another detail here worth mentioning, coming from the fact that *Apple Inc.* is a compound. With open compounds CMOS suggests, though doesn't exactly demand, replacing the hyphen with an en dash. In your case, that would be like this:

> Apple Inc.–owned (en dash)

as opposed to

> Apple Inc.-owned (hyphen).

Here's the relevant passage from CMOS:

(begin quote)
**6.80: En dashes with compound adjectives**

The en dash can be used in place of a hyphen in a compound adjective when one of its elements consists of an open compound or when both elements consist of hyphenated compounds (see 7.82). Whereas a hyphen joins exactly two words, the en dash is intended to signal a link across more than two. Because this editorial nicety will almost certainly go unnoticed by the majority of readers, it should be used sparingly, when a more elegant solution is unavailable. As the first two examples illustrate, the distinction is most helpful with proper compounds, whose limits are made clear within the larger context by capitalization. The relationship in the third example depends to some small degree on an en dash that many readers will perceive as a hyphen connecting *music* and *influenced*. The relationships in the fourth example are less awkwardly conveyed with a comma.

> the post–World War II years
>   Chuck Berry–style lyrics
>   country music–influenced lyrics (*or* lyrics influenced by country music)
>   a quasi-public–quasi-judicial body (*or, better,* a quasi-public, quasi-judicial body)

A single word or prefix should be joined to a hyphenated compound by another hyphen rather than an en dash; if the result is awkward, reword.

> non-English-speaking peoples
>   a two-thirds-full cup (*or, better,* a cup that is two-thirds full)

An abbreviated compound is treated as a single word, so a hyphen, not an en dash, is used in such phrases as “US-Canadian relations” (Chicago’s sense of the en dash does not extend to *between*).
(end quote)

Comment: To avoid possible mistakes it should be pointed out that the rule about full stops(periods) is different in modern British English. You should not put a full stop in if the last letter of the abbreviation is the last letter of the word, so *Dr Smith* but *Prof. Smith*.

Comment: Not in my (British) university! The Profs have to manage without their full stops. But @liguisticum got it right in the first sentence: this is style not grammar and style guides vary.

Comment: +1 for the thorough coverage. In particular, if the poster wants to attach "-owned" to "Apple, Inc," an en-dash, not a hyphen, is the appropriate connector—at least according to Chicago (and some other U.S.) punctuation conventions.